# Getting the background color of a XSSF cell

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

there are already some questions regarding the backgound color of an excel cell but none of the answers solves my problem. I want to get the color as hex. I have a cell with gray background but when I use this code

```
            CellStyle cellStyle = currentRow.getCell(3).getCellStyle();
            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Color color = cellStyle.getFillForegroundColorColor();
            if (color != null) {
             if (color instanceof XSSFColor) {
              System.out.println(currentRow.getCell(3).getAddress() + " XSSF Foreground: " + ((XSSFColor)color).getARGBHex());
             } else if (color instanceof HSSFColor) {
              if (! (color.equals(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.AUTOMATIC.getColor())))
               System.out.println(currentRow.getCell(3).getAddress() + " HSSF Foreground: " + ((HSSFColor)color).getHexString());
             }
            }
            
            CellStyle cellStyle2 = currentRow.getCell(3).getCellStyle();
            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Color color2 = cellStyle2.getFillBackgroundColorColor();
            if (color2 != null) {
             if (color2 instanceof XSSFColor) {
              System.out.println(currentRow.getCell(3).getAddress() + " XSSF Background: " + ((XSSFColor)color2).getARGBHex());
             } else if (color2 instanceof HSSFColor) {
              if (! (color2.equals(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.AUTOMATIC.getColor())))
               System.out.println(currentRow.getCell(3).getAddress() + " HSSF Background: " + ((HSSFColor)color2).getHexString());
             }
            }
            
            System.out.println("Foreground Color: " + currentRow.getCell(3).getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColor());
            System.out.println("Foreground ColorColor: " + currentRow.getCell(3).getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor());
            System.out.println("Background Color: " + currentRow.getCell(3).getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColor());
            System.out.println("Background ColorColor: " + currentRow.getCell(3).getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColorColor());
```

I get

```
D70 XSSF Foreground: FFFFFFFF
D70 XSSF Background: null
Foreground Color: 0
Foreground ColorColor: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor@8288f618
Background Color: 64
Background ColorColor: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor@4813bcba
```

As far as I know Background Color 64 is the index for the AutoColor. FFFFFFFF is not gray.
Any ideas how to change the code to get the HEX color ?

Answer (score 1):

`Excel` cell interiors have pattern fill. The foreground color is the color of the pattern and the background color is the color behind the pattern. Cells having color fill have solid foreground pattern. So only fill foreground color is of interest. The fill background color can be neglected.

Your description in the question shows that you get fill foreground color correct as `XSSFColor` already.

But at least with `Office Open XML` (`XSSF`) there are multiple possibilities of how the color can be set. It may be a `ARGB` hex value set. But it also may be a theme color having a tint value set.

As of my experience best results can be got using [ExtendedColor.getRGBWithTint](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/ExtendedColor.html#getRGBWithTint--).

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellAddress;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;

class ReadExcelCellStyleFillColors {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelExample.xlsx"));
  //Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelExample.xls"));

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    System.out.println("This is cell is " + new CellAddress(cell));

    CellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();

    Color fillFGColor = cellStyle.getFillForegroundColorColor();
    System.out.println("This cell has fill foreground color:");
    System.out.println(fillFGColor);
    if (fillFGColor instanceof ExtendedColor) {
     ExtendedColor extColor = (ExtendedColor)fillFGColor;
     BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(1, extColor.getRGBWithTint());
     System.out.println(bigInteger.toString(16));
    } else if (fillFGColor instanceof HSSFColor) {
     HSSFColor hssfColor = (HSSFColor)fillFGColor; 
     System.out.println(hssfColor.getHexString());
    }

    System.out.println();
   }
  }
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```